# PHP rand(10000000000000,9999999999999) returning "-114888782"

Tags: php

So, I have a PHP script:

```
<?
rand(1000000000000,9999999999999);
```

The expected result is a number with 13 digits.

But it's returning some weird numbers, as:

```
987419207
1032717476
-455563764
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

---

PHP: 5.2.17

OS: Tested on Debian Squeeze and Windows 7, both 64 bits

---

## Solution (workaround)

```
<?
echo rand(10000,99999).rand(10000000,99999999);
```

Comment: Looks like overflow to me.

Comment: Did you check PHP_INT_MAX? Maybe for some reason you are exceeding int max, even though it should be larger on 64 bit

Comment: Overflow plus the fact that 10000000000000 > 9999999999999 will not work, indeed.

Comment: My bad... it was 13 digits on both numbers. Edited

Comment: The largest random number PHP can generate is 2147483647 (or 32767 on some system), so you can not generate 13-digit random numbers. But you can check this answer for a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479823/in-php-how-do-i-generate-a-big-pseudo-random-number

Comment: Take this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587799/why-would-rand-return-a-negative-value-when-min-and-max-values-are-positive

It will help you much in understanding.

Comment: Nice explanation, it's a bit clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use getrandmax() to see the max value that you can get from rand(), its clearly a overflow problem.

you could use 2 of this int and make a longer one, calling rand for a 6 digit and again for a 7 digits, just an idea.

Comment: 2147483647. How do I increase this?

Comment: i dont belive you can, but you could use 2 of this int and make a longer one, calling rand for a 6 digit and again for a 7 digits, just an idea.

Comment: 64-bit php on 64-bit hardware may help - it would certainly provide 64-bit integers (and that number is the max 32-bit signed integer value) [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864058/how-to-have-64-bit-integer-on-php)

Comment: What I have here is *supposed* to be a 64bit hardware. Go figure. Anyway... I just did rand().rand() with 4 digits in one and 9 in the other. It works. Thanks

Comment: and still the other answer with my information is the + 5 and mine +1 haha.

Comment: The dot (concatenation operator) makes the result return as a string.

Answer (score 4):

i think 10000000000000 its not a valid integer!

output

```
getrandmax();
```

Comment: Yeah, 2147483647. No soup for me today, ay?

Answer (score 0):

Use a bignum library like [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php#84734) or [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-random.php). GMP is newer and seems to have a better API but that's just my opinion

Comment: I'm going with the workaround here... I don't need anything fancy for this atm. Thanks!