# rand(0,$var) returns zero when $var is really big

Tags: php

When I run the code below:

```
<?
echo rand(0, 0xfffffffffffffbff); 
echo rand(0, 0xfffffffffffffc00);
echo rand(0, $something_bigger_than_0xfffffffffffffbff);
```

I got something like:

```
-828
0
0
```

(the 2nd and 3rd number will always be zero)

mt_rand() has the same behavior.

so, why zero?

Comment: Works as expected: http://3v4l.org/5OKIC

Comment: Overflow on 32-bit arch, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1587814/2908724

Comment: @AmalMurali edited. still get zero when using 0xfffffffffffffc00 instead of 0xfffffffffffffbff + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass integer value to the `rand()` as the above `$a = 0xfffffffffffffbff;` is a `double` but not an integer value, the double value `0xfffffffffffffbff` will be cast to an integer and eventually you will be getting a zero.

#### An illustration for your understanding.

```
<?php
$a = 0xfffffffffffffbff;

echo gettype($a); //"prints" double

if(is_int($a))
{
    echo "Yes";
}
else
{
    echo "Nope.. casting that to int results in..".intval($a)."<br>"; 
}

echo rand(0, $a);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
double
Nope.. casting that to int results in..0
0
```

Comment: Could you go into more detail how and why `0xfffffffffffffbff` is not an integer value, what is actually is, and how that leads to zeroes?

Comment: @delnan, Added an example of that.

Comment: @delnan: `var_dump` is your friend: https://eval.in/120662 - It is `float(1.844674407371E+19)`

Answer (score 1):

[`rand()`](http://php.net/rand) function takes two integers as its arguments. Integers usually have the maximum range of 2^32. The supplied argument, when converted to integers, will be larger than this, hence causing an integer overflow.

This is actually documented behavior. From the [PHP manual documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting.from-float):

> When converting from float to integer, the number will be rounded
>   towards zero.
>
> If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9
>   = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms), the result is undefined, since the float doesn't have
>   enough precision to give an exact integer result. No warning, not even
>   a notice will be issued when this happens!