# why is a number being converted to negative when putting into php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, highcharts

I am really baffled at this issue and it is driving me nuts, as I really don't understand why a number I am putting into an array is being converted into a weird negative number. Example 1

On the other hand if I insert it without an array, it works fine? Example 2

I need it to be in the format of example 2 so highcharts picks it up as number/datetime and value in json. e.g [1424217600000,10]

Where is the conversion being taken place and why is it doing so?
No matter if I add intval or floatval to $day in example 1 to stop conversion it keeps resulting in `int(-1711542272)`

Does anybody understand what is going on here or why `float(1424217600000)` is being converted to `int(-1711542272)`?

I've tried searching for an answer and have come up with nothing.

```
$result = array();
$start = '2015-02-18';

//Expecting 1424217600000
$day = strtotime($start)*1000; 
var_dump($day); // $day = float(1424217600000)

Example 1: Adding it as an additonal array
$result['data'][] = array($day => 1); //$day = int(-1711542272)

Example 2: Adding straight into array
$result['data'][] = $day; // $day = float(1424217600000)
```

Comment: Where's the conversion happening, in PHP or Javascript?

Comment: All the code above is in pure PHP. I have put the code exactly as I have tried fixing the problem codes above, nothing more or nothing less. Why when adding it as array($day => 1) converts $day into [-1711542272]?

Comment: Number is larger than the range of a 32-bit signed integer, and you can't use anything other than an int or a string as an array key

Comment: is that a limitation of putting stuff in array key or PHP limitation? If so does float have the same limitation? Does this mean I can not have any key in int or float as long as that?

Comment: It means that the numeric value is being cast implicitly to an integer when you use it as a key in the array, and integers are limited to 32-bit signed values when you're using 32-bit PHP

Comment: If you switch to using a 64-bit version of PHP, then it will cast successfully to a 64-bit signed integer

Comment: Alternatively, try casting it explicitly to a string

Comment: Thanks Mark, you've helped me at least understand the issue at hand. Now I need to find an alternative format in highcharts because if I cast it to a string. Highcharts does not recognize it

Comment: How do I accept your answer?

Comment: If you need that values for Highcharts, then in JS use `parseInt(value, 10)` to parse strings into numbers. Then use that numbers in Highcharts as data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would rand() return a negative value when min and max values are positive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587799/why-would-rand-return-a-negative-value-when-min-and-max-values-are-positive)